# How can I get a single value from a mysql result, if I have several rows with the same value

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a database called 'employees' with this values:

```
value1     | value2 | value3
-----------------------------
employee1  |  key1  |  boss1
employee2  |  key2  |  boss1
employee3  |  key3  |  boss1
employee4  |  key4  |  boss2
employee5  |  key5  |  boss2
```

In php, I'm trying to loop through the result to get all the employees of a boss, but getting the boss name only once, I've tried with `GROUP BY`, but when looping this only shows the first entry:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE value3 = 'boss1' GROUP BY value3";
$result = $db->query($query);
$foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row["value1"] . $row["value2"] . $row["value3"];
}
```

Results in:

```
employee1  |  key1  |  boss1
```

Whitout `GROUP BY`, when looping with `foreach`, it shows the boss name once for each entry

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE value3 = 'boss1'";
$result = $db->query($query);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row["value1"] . $row["value2"] . $row["value3"];
}
```

Results in:

```
employee1  |  key1  |  boss1
employee2  |  key2  |  boss1
employee3  |  key3  |  boss1
```

I'm trying to get a result like:

```
boss1
    employee1  |  key1
    employee2  |  key2
    employee3  |  key3
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have too much data? Why not just ignore the extra data then?

Comment: You are mixing up data formatting with data retrieval.  After retrieving the data, clean it up separately.  Don't try to clean the data with your SQL.

Comment: I need to identify which employee goes with which boss, but I want to display the boss only once, and a list of this boss employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a `comma`(default) delimited list of `value1` and `values2` for each `boss` like this:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(e.value1) AS value1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(e.value2) AS value2,
  e.value3 AS boss
FROM employees e
WHERE value3 = 'boss1' 
GROUP BY value3;
```

This will get you something like for `boss1`:

`employee1,employee2,employee3 | key1,key2,key3 | boss1`

> Edit 1: `As a html list, something like: <ul>boss1 <li>employee1</li> <li>employee2</li> <li>employee3</li> </ul> I don't need the html code, but I need to get the data in a format which I can use as a list in html`

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('<ul>',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<li>',e.value1,'<\/li>')),'<\/ul>') AS value1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(e.value2) AS value2,
  e.value3 AS boss
FROM employees e
WHERE value3 = 'boss1' 
GROUP BY value3;
```

*Note*:- You should use your server side language to achieve this. And use first query.

Comment: Close enough, is there a way to display the results in a list???
I've been smashing my head against the keyboard since yesterday, and I haven't been able to get the results in a list.

Comment: As a html list, something like:

    <ul>boss1
        <li>employee1</li>
        <li>employee2</li>
        <li>employee3</li>
    </ul>

I don't need the html code, but I need to get the data in a format which I can use as a list in html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if()` in `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $i++;
    if ($i==1) {echo $row["value3"];}
    echo $row["value1"] . $row["value2"];
}
```

Than, you can get the result you wanted:

```
boss1
employee1  |  key1
employee2  |  key2
employee3  |  key3
```